# Automatic mesh fill generation as two edges bend away from each other

Tags: mesh

While animating two cube primatives bending away from each other I'd like Blender to fill in the gap with a neat curved mesh? Is this possible?

Hopefully the images convey better what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: start]

[image: 45 degrees]

[image: 90 degrees]

and so on...

Thoughts?

Thanks
Jacques